# How can I use 'interval' Rxjs function without executing Change Detection routine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, setinterval

I want to show the live server time in the app. Then I created a component that uses RXJS 'interval' function to update the time every second but this executes Change Detection routine every second!

How can I update the time without triggering change detection?

This is my component:

**server-time.component.ts:**

```js
export class ServerTimeComponent implements OnInit {
  serverTime: Date;
  serverDatetime: InfoDatetime;

  constructor(private infoService: InfoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getServerDate();

    // Increase time by interval
    interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      // Skip if the time is not ready
      if (this.serverTime === undefined) {
        return;
      }

      // Update the time
      this.serverTime = new Date(this.serverTime.getTime() + 1000);
      // If it's midnight, get the date again
      if (
        this.serverTime.getHours() === 0 &&
        this.serverTime.getMinutes() === 0 &&
        this.serverTime.getSeconds() < 2
      ) {
        this.getServerDate();
      }
    });
  }

  getServerDate() {
    this.infoService
      .getServerDatetime()
      .subscribe((res: ApiResponse<InfoDatetime>) => {
        if (res.code === 1) {
          this.serverDatetime = res.data;

          // Create a new Date. Time part will be used
          this.serverTime = new Date('2000-01-01 ' + this.serverDatetime.time);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**server-time.component.html:**

```html
<span *ngIf="serverDatetime">
  <span class="ml-1">{{serverTime | date:'hh:mm:ss'}}</span>
  —
  <span class="mr-1">{{serverDatetime?.date_jalali}}</span>
</span>
```

And this is the reproduced problem in stackblitz.io:

https://angular-ibcvbp.stackblitz.io

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NgZone runOutsideAngular method

```
export class ServerTimeComponent implements OnInit {
  serverTime: Date;
  serverDatetime: InfoDatetime;

  constructor(private infoService: InfoService, public zone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getServerDate();

    // Increase time by interval

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular( ()=> {
        interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      // Skip if the time is not ready
      if (this.serverTime === undefined) {
        return;
      }

      // Update the time
      this.serverTime = new Date(this.serverTime.getTime() + 1000);
      // If it's midnight, get the date again
      if (
        this.serverTime.getHours() === 0 &&
        this.serverTime.getMinutes() === 0 &&
        this.serverTime.getSeconds() < 2
      ) {
        this.getServerDate();
      }
    });

    });

  }

  getServerDate() {
    this.infoService
      .getServerDatetime()
      .subscribe((res: ApiResponse<InfoDatetime>) => {
        if (res.code === 1) {
          this.serverDatetime = res.data;

          // Create a new Date. Time part will be used
          this.serverTime = new Date('2000-01-01 ' + this.serverDatetime.time);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this methods stops change detection but then the time value in the view is not updated too! Should I update that using pure JS or there is another method? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqr4bw

Comment: when you want to update the value you can Inject ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor and call the method this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck(); after you assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  // add this to the constructor to inject zone
  constructor(public zone: NgZone, ...args) { }
```

And use zone to trigger change detection for variable.

```
  interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      // Skip if the time is not ready
      if (this.serverTime === undefined) {
        return;
      }

      // Update the time
      this.zone.run(() => this.serverTime = new Date(this.serverTime.getTime() + 1000))
      // If it's midnight, get the date again
      if (
        this.serverTime.getHours() === 0 &&
        this.serverTime.getMinutes() === 0 &&
        this.serverTime.getSeconds() < 2
      ) {
        this.getServerDate();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. but using 'run' method did not helped. The change detection is still running every second! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmmfse

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that you not clear the previous interval or unsubscribe it. Like:

```
if(this.interval !== undefined) { 
  clearInterval(this.interval); //this.interval.unsubscribe();
}
this.interval =  interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
```